# Drawable has unresolved theme attributes exception on EditText click

Tags: android, exception, android-studio, android-edittext

My app throws exception when I click on EditText(I don't what's the cause: EditText or opeden keyboard). I saw it coulde be caused by using Resources.getDrawable() but i don't do that. Can anyone help?

Here's the log:

```
W/Resources: Drawable android:drawable/text_cursor_material has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme) or Context.getDrawable(int).
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException
                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:797)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
                                                                at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.getHotspotX(Editor.java:3772)
                                                                at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updateDrawable(Editor.java:3399)
                                                                at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.<init>(Editor.java:3390)
                                                                at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.<init>(Editor.java:3728)
                                                                at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.getHandle(Editor.java:4036)
                                                                at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.access$200(Editor.java:4000)
                                                                at android.widget.Editor.onTouchUpEvent(Editor.java:1621)
                                                                at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8034)
                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8476)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2372)
                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2791)
                                                                at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8671)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4164)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4030)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3580)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3633)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3599)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3716)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3607)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3773)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3580)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3633)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3599)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3607)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3580)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5848)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5822)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5793)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5938)
                                                                at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                at android.os.Message
```

**UPD**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/activity_enter_login_field"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_border"
        android:hint="login"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey"/>
```

**UPD 2**
I've just created a sample project and the error still appears. I have an acivity which only sets layout in `onCreate`.
Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="text"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The issue might appear because of the libraries I use, so here's the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
}
```

**EDIT 3**

I've also updated build tools up to 23.0.3 and support libraries up to 23.3.0.
The error is still there.

Comment: Can you post the code.

Comment: @nakul the code of which part? The exception is thrown when i click the EditText and none of my code is executed.

Comment: add the code of the edit text were you have initialised it

Comment: @nakul i've posted the code

Comment: can u you post the code inside your activity

Comment: by seeing your logcat message try to replace 
context.getResources().getDrawable(int) 
by

context.getDrawable(int)

Comment: @nakul i never do that. I'll try to make a sample project to show you the cource code, because now there's really a lot.

Comment: @nakul i've made a project where there's no code at all and the error still occures.

Comment: When you press a TextEdit, text handles appear to help you select text and position the caret. You can override the text handles appearance in your app theme. That's probably the cause of this problem. While the text editor was trying to resolve the text handle, it threw this error,